# get the quantity of product by code

Tags: product, quantity

i am using the following code

```
<?php echo $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId())->getSku();?>
```

to display the sku ,

in the same way i want to display the quantity also.

as quantity is not an attribute , i can not able to get how to display the quantity.

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the product qty by following code.

```
<?php 
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());
    echo $product->getSku();

    /* To get stock qty */

    echo (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $products->getQty();?>
```

Comment: <?php 
$num= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); 
echo "Remaining products: ".$num;
?>

Answer (score 0):

Here a code get product stock & sku

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());
    $productStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    echo $_product->getSku();
    echo $productStock->getQty();
    echo $productStock->getMinQty();
    echo $productStock->getMinSaleQty();
```

Comment: Same as accepted answer?

Comment: it's showing  echo $productStock->getQty(); echo $productStock->getMinQty();
    echo $productStock->getMinSaleQty();